# <Cordova/CDVLocalStorage.h> not found

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, wkwebview

While I am adding "cordova-plugin-wkwebview" in my cordova 5.4.0 project I am getting "Cordova/CDVLocalStorage.h not found".header. The search path is set to "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include".

Comment: Why do people downvote without leaving at least a comment? I have seen worse questions where everyone would elaborate why it is so bad, meanwhile this is a concrete problem and a fine question (apart from the form maybe).

Answer (score 0):

It seems the plugin breaks cordova-ios-4.x, you have to downgrade to cordova-ios-3.x: https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/WKWebView/issues/209